# "An error occurred when submitting a question." but without any detail

Tags: bug

Sun Oct 16 11:36:12 PDT 2016 I was trying to post a new question into Software Recommendations:

[image: Annotated screenshot of error]

No indication at all was given as to what the error was.

If this was a case of "the site went down" or something of that nature, then that should be what was stated. At this point, I am stuck and have to manually save off my text I was going to post for later to try again.

EDIT #1: I got the same error again when trying to post to Software Recommendations Meta. This time I got an error saying it looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this was due to my having a proxy active in my browser. So this seems to be a general meta stack exchange question, and as such I posted a new question into [Is asking questions on Stack Exchange sites using a proxy prohibited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285858/is-asking-questions-to-stackexchange-sites-using-a-proxy-prohibited)

Comment: This sounds probable. You'd get that red box when anything client-side prevents posting - including network errors.